# Correct community for programming and OS-related problems with emulator

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm about to ask a question about a problem I have with an emulator that I want to run under Linux. But I have a hard time figuring out which community is best suited for it.

- It is a development/testing specific tool and as such it would be
  **appropriate for Stack Overflow.**
- The Windows version runs fine; my problems are with the Linux version. Thus it would be a **possible Super User question.**
- I have a hunch that it is related to the [Ubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29)
  environment, since the original developers seems to have
  used [Red Hat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux). And by that it **could fit into [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/tour).**

The question I intend to ask:

**************** Question start ************************

I run into an error when I try to execute the [AGA simulator](https://developer.lindholmen.se/redmine/projects/aga/wiki/Simulator) on my Ubuntu 14.10 machine. The error message I get is

```
Graphics Device initialization failed for: es2, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:280)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:220)
...

    Exception thrown from main method of combitech/aga/SimulatorApplication
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:185)

...

    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$3/22713019.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

At the same machine booting Windows 8, the application executes without any error. I'm not sure if this is an error because of faulty environment variables, bad graphics drivers or some other incompatibility. This [thread suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21185156/javafx-on-linux-is-showing-a-graphics-device-initialization-failed-for-es2-s) that it is a [JavaFX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX) error and to start the program with `-Dprism.verbose=true`. But that is not possible since the emulator is distributed with a wrapper executable to start it.

Googling the error does not give any further suggestion than to check that my GTK version is above 2.18. Which it seems to be:

```
ii  libgtk-3-0:amd 3.12.2-0ubun amd64        GTK+ graphical user interface lib
ii  libgtk2.0-0:am 2.24.25-0ubu amd64        GTK+ graphical user interface lib
```

Any suggestions or opinions?

Now this qustion is [asked on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29192817/java-fx-dependant-emulator-fails-to-run-under-linux) with `java` and `Javafx` tags and also, as Jason C noted, [about ten days ago on AU.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/596044/javafx-dependant-program-fails-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: @rene I edited the meta question with a draft of my actual question.

Comment: This is a javafx question.  I would venture it is safe to ask it as a java+javafx question on SO.

Comment: The question was just sent to SO. Let's just wait and see what the community suggests.

Answer (score 12):

This is a tricky one. I would argue that it definitely does not belong on SU, as AGA Simulator is a programming tool. It would probably end up just being migrated to SO (they tend to migrate anything that looks programming-related to SO there, regardless of details).

It could work on SO as it is a problem with a programming tool, although to make it more palatable to the trigger happy casual reader you may want to mention explicitly that you are using the simulator as part of the testing process for an application you are developing (presumably).

It could arguably work on AU as well, if it is an Ubuntu-specific issue (or [unix.se](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) if it is not unique to Ubuntu, [as Braiam observed in a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288488/correct-community-for-programming-and-os-related-problems-with-emulator/288499#comment168071_288499)). However, my gut feeling is that the user base on SO may be more well-equipped to answer the question.

In my opinion, it can work on either SO or AU/unix, but slightly more on the SO side of the fence. I recommend asking it on SO and, if it is closed or no answer is received after a reasonably long amount of time, taking it to unix instead.

---

Reading [rene's ex-answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288500/616460), I now also see that you have [already asked on AU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/596044/javafx-dependant-program-fails-on-ubuntu-14-04). That was 9 days ago, and I'd say it's safe to assume you probably won't get a response there. It's up to you if you want to mention in your SO question that you did ask on AU and gave it a sufficient time but did not receive an answer.

Comment: Is not a Ubuntu specific issue, I'm able to reproduce 100% the issue on Debian.

Comment: "they tend to migrate anything that looks programming-related to SO there, regardless of details" -- a process we happily reprocicate by indiscriminately directing all *not* programming-related questions their way 

Comment: @Jongware Oh trust me, you will see no defensiveness on my part about this matter. I feel even more sorry for programmers.se.

Comment: As suggested, I just posted it on SO. Mets question updated with link to SO.